# Easiest way to change altacv.cls to a single column

Tags: columns, layout

I really like some of the basic features of the AltaCV template (https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV) but don't like the 2 column layout. What'd be the easiest way to change the template to a single column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [example file on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/altacv-template/trgqjpwnmtgv) a command `\columnratio{0.6}` is called to set the column ratio to 60/40. Then a `paracol` environment is started with two columns using `\begin{paracol}{2}`.

Changing these two lines leads to a single-column layout:

```
%% Set the left/right column width ratio to 1:0.
\columnratio{1.0}

% Start a 1-column paracol.
\begin{paracol}{1}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.